# Rails upgrade to 4.1.12 causes ActiveAdmin crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

We have an app that we're upgrading from Rails 3.2.x to 4.1.x.  After much tweaking, the app runs now, but trying to load the ActiveAdmin dashboard, we get this error:

```
Showing /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre1/app/views/active_admin/page/index.html.arb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `call' for #<Pano::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd869a3c138>
Extracted source (around line #2):
1

  insert_tag active_admin_application.view_factory["page"]

Rails.root: /Users/xxx/Google Drive/Code/xxxx/xxxx-rails
```

The code that is causing the crash is in the ActiveAdmin code itself:

/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre1/app/views/active_admin/page/index.html.arb

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, can anyone potentially point me in the right direction?

Comment: For posterity - we ended up going to Rails 4.2.3 instead of 4.1.12.  The newer version had a few issues, but we were able to work around those.